# C# MVC Query String Encoding and Decoding

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes, cryptography

I want to encode and decode the url parameters.

calling function in javascript

```
var url = '/Demo/Demo?id=58';
$(location).attr('href', url)
```

Current url parameter

> www.example.com/Demo/Demo?id=58

code in Demo controller

```
public ActionResult Demo(int id)
{
   return view();
}
```

i want the above url to be changed like the bolow line

> www.example.com/Demo/Demo?id=Sff5f8ddg

So that the id value will be confidential. what is the best way to encode and decode.

> Note: we calling method by anchor tag, ajax and jquery. Encoding and Decoding other than Base64

Is there any cryptography method other than Base64 enoding and decoding like encrypt in javascript and decrypt in C# method

Comment: if you pass confidential params you do not use querystring parameter but you can use post parameter

Comment: share some example for post parameters

Comment: Is your favorite search engine down?

Comment: any best way to encode the query string in url

Comment: then you are mentioning that the parameters can't be encrypted?

Comment: It depends on (a) if you just want to obfuscate your parameter or (b) secure your parameters. I would go with what @hazzik said and use GUID. If there is an issue with `user N` needing appropriate privilege to access the action then you need to check this before performing anything with the passed ID on the server side.

Comment: @anand there is no reason to use weak encryption or obfuscation. HTTPS already protects the URL and you *can't* not use HTTPS nowadays.

Comment: The value will never be confidential as it's in the JS code which is browsable by the user.

Comment: use .cs code to access query string

Answer (score 7):

> So that the id value will be confidential. what is the best way to encode and decode.

It won't. At least in the way you are trying to make it. As soon as you encode the [internal] id it becomes the public id for that entry. It does not matter for user which id to use: `58` or `Sff5f8ddg`, as it would refer to the same entry in the system. If you are using unsalted algorithms it would prevent only not so sophisticated users to discover other entries in your system.

As I understand the problem you are trying to solve is - how to make other entries undiscoverable by having an id for some entry(ies). Eg, if user has an url for entry 58, they should not be able to find entries 57 and 59.

The solution is: use GUIDs as ID for your entries.

Also, you need to make sure that you've implemented proper access control for your entries.

Comment: As the GUID's are linked to an id and anyone can recognize a GUID, it will be a matter of time before all available GUID's are detected.

Comment: @RuardvanElburg Sorry, WAT? Good luck... [`the number of random version 4 UUIDs which need to be generated in order to have a 50% probability of at least one collision is 2.71 quintillion [...] This number is equivalent to generating 1 billion UUIDs per second for about 85 years`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Collisions). Can I have your permission to print out your comment and put it on my wall?

Comment: Also, why would I even need to link an GUID to an arbitrary integral ID?

Answer (score 1):

In javascript, you can use

```
var str = "Hello World!";
var enc = window.btoa(str);
var dec = window.atob(enc);
```

The result of res will be:

```
Encoded String: SGVsbG8gV29ybGQh
Decoded String: Hello World!
```

This example shows you how to use the RijndaelManaged for encryption decryption.

```
 public static class Cryptography
    {

        private static readonly byte[] _key = { 0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03 };
        private static readonly byte[] _iV = { 0x10, 0x11, 0x12, 0x13, 0x10, 0x11, 0x12, 0x13, 0x10, 0x11, 0x12, 0x13, 0x10, 0x11, 0x12, 0x13 };

        #region Encryption


        public static string Encrypt(this string inputText)
        {
            string _encryptString = string.Empty;
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(inputText))
                return string.Empty;
            else
            {
                ASCIIEncoding textConverter = new ASCIIEncoding();
                RijndaelManaged myRijndael = new RijndaelManaged();

                ICryptoTransform encryptor = myRijndael.CreateEncryptor(_key, _iV);
                MemoryStream msEncrypt = new MemoryStream();
                CryptoStream csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write);
                byte[] toEncrypt = textConverter.GetBytes(inputText);
                csEncrypt.Write(toEncrypt, 0, toEncrypt.Length);
                csEncrypt.FlushFinalBlock();
                _encryptString = Convert.ToBase64String(msEncrypt.ToArray()).Replace(" ", "+");
                return _encryptString;
            }
        }

        public static string Decrypt(this string inputText)
        {
            string text = inputText;
            try
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(inputText))
                    return string.Empty;
                else
                {
                    inputText = inputText.Replace(" ", "+");

                    byte[] encrypted = Convert.FromBase64String(inputText);
                    ASCIIEncoding textConverter = new ASCIIEncoding();
                    RijndaelManaged myRijndael = new RijndaelManaged();

                    ICryptoTransform decryptor = myRijndael.CreateDecryptor(_key, _iV);
                    MemoryStream msDecrypt = new MemoryStream(encrypted);
                    CryptoStream csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read);
                    byte[] fromEncrypt = new byte[encrypted.Length];
                    csDecrypt.Read(fromEncrypt, 0, fromEncrypt.Length);
                    return textConverter.GetString(fromEncrypt).TrimEnd('\x0');
                }
            }
            catch (FormatException)
            {
                return "";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return text;
            }
        }



        #endregion Encryption

    }
```

Now encrypt decrypt in controller Like

```
 "id".Encrypt();///
  "encryptID".Decrypt();
```

Comment: can u share sample code for javascript and controller method

Comment: RijndaelManaged myRijndael = new RijndaelManaged(); showing error

Comment: You need to add namespace
"using System.Security.Cryptography"

Comment: method -> public ActionResult Demo(int id). then the int datatype will return error

Comment: you have to convert int value in string like "58".Encrypt()

Comment: like public ActionResult Demo(int id.Encrypt()) right

Comment: Browsers already offer encryption through HTTPS. The javascript snippet doesn't encrypt anything. The AES code is useless if the *client* can't encrypt the URL.

Answer (score 1):

What I am able to understand from your question is that you want to restrict user from being able to know the exact value of the id parameter.

But that's not gonna help because you already have that value on your browser/client side.
so you have id on your client and you want to restrict your client from knowing its value.
An average developer(anyone who write code) can access your value using developer tool of browser.
So no benefit.

Another way is you send your id encrypted from server itself.
For that you can use the solution provided by @Karan Singh.
Or any other option you want to explore for that matter is up to you.

One suggestion try to use an encryption method which can not be done in reverse. This will add overhead in processing as you will have to first encrypt your Id from DB and then match it with the value sent by client.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use jquery function like:

`var encodedUrl = encodeURIComponent("your url"); //'/Demo/Demo?id=58';
console.log(encodedUrl);`

Thank you

Comment: it is returning "Server Error in '/' Application." on clicking

Comment: I got a perfact result like : %2FDemo%2FDemo%3Fid%3D58

Comment: id 58 is visible

Answer (score 0):

```
var id=Encrypt(YourID);
var id=Decrypt(YourID);

  using System.Security.Cryptography;

public static string Encrypt(string inputText)
    {
        string encryptionkey = "SAUW193BX628TD57";
        byte[] keybytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(encryptionkey.Length.ToString());
        RijndaelManaged rijndaelCipher = new RijndaelManaged();
        byte[] plainText = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(inputText);
        PasswordDeriveBytes pwdbytes = new PasswordDeriveBytes(encryptionkey, keybytes);
        using (ICryptoTransform encryptrans = rijndaelCipher.CreateEncryptor(pwdbytes.GetBytes(32), pwdbytes.GetBytes(16)))
        {
            using (MemoryStream mstrm = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (CryptoStream cryptstm = new CryptoStream(mstrm, encryptrans, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                cryptstm.Write(plainText, 0, plainText.Length);
                cryptstm.Close();
                return Convert.ToBase64String(mstrm.ToArray());
                }
            }
        }
    }

public static string Decrypt(string encryptText)
{
    string encryptionkey = "SAUW193BX628TD57";
    byte[] keybytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(encryptionkey.Length.ToString());
    RijndaelManaged rijndaelCipher = new RijndaelManaged();
    byte[] encryptedData = Convert.FromBase64String(encryptText.Replace(" ", "+"));
    PasswordDeriveBytes pwdbytes = new PasswordDeriveBytes(encryptionkey, keybytes);
    using (ICryptoTransform decryptrans = rijndaelCipher.CreateDecryptor(pwdbytes.GetBytes(32), pwdbytes.GetBytes(16)))
    {
        using (MemoryStream mstrm = new MemoryStream(encryptedData))
        {
            using (CryptoStream cryptstm = new CryptoStream(mstrm, decryptrans, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
            {
            byte[] plainText = new byte[encryptedData.Length];
            int decryptedCount = cryptstm.Read(plainText, 0, plainText.Length);
            return Encoding.Unicode.GetString(plainText, 0, decryptedCount);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If what you are looking to do is to hide the 58 from the rendered content (client-side), then you need to implement an encryption/decryption scheme on the backend and pass that value from/to the client side as needed.

When you provide data to the client, your server side code will encrypt the 58 into some string in order to conceal the real value and pass that to the client.

When the client issues a request to you, it should use that encrypted string that you provided before and your server should decrypt it into something it can use.

You don't need JavaScript to encrypt and C# to decrypt the values. The JavaScript portion should be working off of the encrypted id at all times since it's scripting that is executing *after the fact* at the client side. How the value is consumed on the server side is an internal aspect of which the client-side JavaScript does not need to know about.

Answer (score 0):

Hello anand i think you want to create a temper proof Query string [Download the code from github repository](https://github.com/Mohan421/URLEncryption)

Answer (score -1):

controller:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult SubmitInputTest(int id) { 
            //your code 
            //do stuff

            return RedirectToAction("index");
        }
```

In your view (cshtml):

```
<form id="frmToSubmit" action="<controller>/SubmitInputTest">
 <hidden id="id" name="id"/>
</form>
```

In your javascript:

```
$('#id').attr('value', [your ID Value]);
$('#frmToSubmit').submit();
```

Comment: its not a form. just <a> tag

Comment: Where you specify that you want to use <A> tag??? if you execute a javascript function you can create a form on demand and post it

Comment: i wont use form